# How do I unblock LDAP users in GitLab-CE

Tags: git, ldap, gitlab, gitlab-ce

Some of our GitLab users who where authenticated through LDAP got blocked when the LDAP authentication user account was locked.
How can I unlock them?
GitLab-EE seems to provide this feature by force syncing the LDAP state.
How can I do that with GitLab-CE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I basically went straight into the database:

`sudo -u gitlab-psql /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/psql -h /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql -d gitlabhq`

and

`update public.users set state='active';`

**Note:** this will unblock *all* users

Comment: There's a high likelihood that the users will become blocked again using this method. While this works temporarily, it's best to find the solution to prevent it.

Comment: You're all partially right, but have you actually had that specific problem? The problem is that the user we used for ldap authentication was blocked not a user authenticated by ldap. In the ee version there is a forced ldap sync for that.  This is missing in the CE edition. Which basically means any user Gitlab blocked because of the ldap user is blocked forever,  unless you can tell me how to do this in an more appropriate way.

Comment: If you use the rails console (`sudo gitlab-rails console -e production`), to unblock a specific user, you can call:
`User.find_by(email: 'user@your.domain').update!(state: 'active')`

Answer (score 12):

I had a user with state `ldap_blocked`
To fix, I went `user.state='active'` which returned `=> "active"` then I did `user.unlock_access!` for good measure (probably not necessary).
User was then unblocked in the web console.

### More Detail

I followed instructions here: https://docs.gitlab.com/12.10/ee/security/unlock_user.html

Which involves getting into the ruby console:

```rb
sudo gitlab-rails console -e production
```

Then searching for the user and saving in a temporary variable:

```rb
userJohn = User.find_by(email: 'john.smith@yourdomain.com')
userJohn.state
=> "ldap_blocked"
```

I then deviated slightly from the instructions by setting user to active directly which seemed to work (the instructions said `userJohn.unlock_access!` which didn't work for me)

```rb
userJohn.state='active'
=> "active"
userJohn.state #me checking to make sure
=> "active"
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to do 'userJohn.save' at the end for the change to stick.

Comment: Indeed calling `userJohn.state='active'` will just modify the local copy of the user.
Alternativaly to calling 'save' after playing with the object, you can directly modify it with `userJohn.update!(state: 'active')`

Answer (score 1):

If an LDAP user becomes blocked, it usually means:

1. The connection to the LDAP server was interrupted or otherwise didn't work (bad admin credentials in the configuration file)
2. The user no longer exists in LDAP.

If the user still exists in LDAP but it still being blocked randomly it probably indicates a sporadic communication problem with the LDAP server. In this case, trying to sign in again should work and will unblock the user.

Comment: It can also mean that the account is temporarily or permanently locked in LDAP.

Comment: Signing in again doesn't solve problem, that's  probably  the first thing we tried

Comment: What helped was deleting the user and signing it up fresh  and losing all user related info by that.

Comment: Are you re-creating the user manually, or by having the person sign in again with LDAP after the deletion? I still believe this is a sporadic communication problem.

Comment: I exactly know what the communication problem was,  the ldap authentication user was blocked. When that happens,  any ldap user trying to authenticate when it is blocked gets marked as blocked by Gitlab CE. After that I tried deleting the user and signing it up again via login with the implication that everything related to the user is deleted. There is no way I'm aware of that solves this without deleting the user except the solution I posted here

Answer (score 1):

After ten failed login attempts a user gets in a locked state.

To unlock a locked user:

1. SSH into your GitLab server.
2. Start a Ruby on Rails console:

For Omnibus GitLab:

```
sudo gitlab-rails console -e production
```

For installations from source:

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rails console -e production
```

Find the user to unlock. You can search by email or ID.

```
user = User.find_by(email: 'admin@local.host')
```

or

```
user = User.where(id: 1).first
```

Unlock the user:

```
user.unlock_access!
user.save
```

Exit the console with Control+d

The user should now be able to log in.

Comment: Did not work for me on GitLab 14.9.5 for some reason. @Gostega's user.state='active' did though.

Answer (score 0):

To complete [Gostega](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5167528/gostega) answer, if you have a long list of users you can use the following script:

```
ldap_blocked_users = User.where(state: 'ldap_blocked')

ldap_blocked_users.each do |user|
  puts "Username: #{user.username}, Email: #{user.email}"
  user.update!(state: 'active')
end
```